# What is main difference between "auto" and "instancetype" type?

Tags: ios, objective-c

What is difference between `auto` and clang type `instancetype`?
Where we have to use `auto` and where we have to user `instancetype`?

Comment: Don't be confused with C++11 `auto` keyword which is different with C `auto` keyword and works only in C++11 context.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`auto` in Objective C is inherited from C and means [auto keyword](http://tigcc.ticalc.org/doc/keywords.html#auto)

> Defines a local variable as having a local lifetime.
>
> Keyword auto uses the following syntax:
>
> [auto] data-definition; As the local lifetime is the default for local
>   variables, auto keyword is extremely rarely used.
>
> Note: GNU C extends auto keyword to allow forward declaration of
>   nested functions.

If you are looking for equivalent for C++11's `auto` or C#'s `var` - in Objective C `id` is used.

```
id a = [NSString new];
id b = [NSNumber new];
```

But `id` is not resolved to concrete type at compile time like `auto` in C++11 does.

`instancetype` is a contextual keyword that can be used as a result type to signal that a method returns a related result type. For example:

```
@interface Person
+ (instancetype)personWithName:(NSString *)name;
@end
```

[instancetype](http://nshipster.com/instancetype/), unlike id, can only be used as the result type in a method declaration.

With instancetype, the compiler will correctly infer that the result of +personWithName: is an instance of a Person. And will generate an error if you will try to call

```
[[Person personWithName:@"Some Name"] methodThatNotExistsInPerson];
```

If you will use `id` compiler will not do so, you will not fix it and will receive runtime error!

Instancetype is used to add a little more "strong typing"to Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean `auto` they are unrelated.

- `auto` is a C99 storage class. Storage classes define the scope and visibility of variables and functions. `auto` is the default for local variables without a specifier. The others are `extern`, `register`, `static`. Objective-C also has `__block`, and C11 has `_Thread_local`.
- `instancetype` indicates that the return type is an instance of the <strike>enclosing</strike><sup>1</sup> receiving class. It can be returned from an Objective-C method, but not passed as an argument. If you use it instead `id`, LLVM will detect wrong assignments between different types. Use it in constructors and static initializers.

<sup>1</sup> Receiving class is a better term because subclasses don't need to redefine `instancetype` for it to return the subclass type.

Comment: Sorry this is incorrect, it is not "enclosing class" but "receiving class" - and the distinction is the key.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others `auto` is a rarely used keyword, forget about it.

`instancetype` is a recent introduction which allows for methods to follow the `init` pattern. In Objective-C methods which start with `init` return an object whose type is that of the *receiving class* - in other words the type of `self` within the method. An `init` method is said to have a *related result type*. Consider:

```
@interface A : NSObject

- (id) initWithString:(NSString *)text;

@end

@interface B : A

@end
```

Then for the expression:

```
[[A alloc] initWithString:@"An instance of A"]
```

the compiler knows that the type of the result is `A *` rather than the less specific `id` declared for `initWithString:` because `initX` methods have a related result type.

Further more for the expression:

```
 [[B alloc] initWithString:@"An instance of B"]
```

the compiler knows that the type of the result is `B *` as though the method invoked comes from class `A` (by inheritance) it is called on an instance of `B`.

The introduction of `instancetype` allows other methods to declare they follow this pattern, thus giving the compiler more precise type information - which, for instance, it can use to resolve property references. Consider:

```
@interface A : NSObject

// returns an instance of A or whatever subtype of A it is called on
+ (instancetype) locateWithString:(NSString *)text;

@end

@interface B : A

@property NSInteger size;

@end
```

The for the expression:

```
[B locateWithString:@"An instance of B"].size
```

the compiler knows that `locateWithString:` returns a `B *` and so has a property `size`. Prior to `instancetype` the type `id` would have had to be used, and the type `id` has no property `size` so the compiler would have produced an error.